# Concatenate OR conditional expressions from list to "|"

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

This probably is a python lang related question, not precisely of boto3 lib:

That query works:

```
matches = table.query(
    IndexName="status-date-index",
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('status').eq('next'),
    FilterExpression=Attr('teams').contains('a') | Attr('teams').contains('b') | Attr('teams').contains('c')
)
```

But I will have a varible list  `["a", "b", "c", ...N]` and need to convert them to

```
filter_expression = Attr('teams').contains('a') | Attr('teams').contains('b') | Attr('teams').contains('c') | ...N
```

any ideas how to do it in python? or maybe I need to do a better FilterExpression for that case?

[boto3.dynamodb.conditions.Attr reference.](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/boto3/dynamodb/conditions.html)

Comment: What logic applies to the `'teams'` and `'cali'` parts of the calls you've shown? How do they relate to the list of letters you're asking about? Is there actually two lists, with the arguments to the two calls? If so, you probably want `zip`. Or do they alternate in some way? If neither of those, I have no idea what you want.

Comment: fixed. the correct snipped is: `Attr('teams').contains('a') | Attr('teams').contains('b') | Attr('teams').contains('c')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) on the list of items produced by `contains` (which I assume to be of type `ConditionBase`), with the [`or_` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.or_).  You can also couple that with [`functools.map`](https://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.map) on the strings since you have a pile of similar inputs.  Consider this much simplified example:

```
>>> from functools import map
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import or_
>>> values = ['9', '3', '7', '32']
>>> map(int, values)
[9, 3, 7, 32]
>>> reduce(or_, map(int, values))
47
```

Exact equivalent to

```
>>> 9 | 3 | 7 | 32
47
```

To further simplify the generation of `Condition` objects from `Attr(field).contains(value)`, a list of 2-tuple can be constructed, like so (based on your original question) through list-comprehension:

```
raw_conditions = [
    ('teams', 'a'),
    ('b', 'cali'),
    ('teams', 'c'),
]

conditions = [Attr(field).contains(value) for field, value in raw_conditions]
filter_expression = reduce(or_, conditions)
```

Comment: What if there is a need to build a condition in the general case that covers the possibility of an empty list in raw_conditions?

Comment: @Andriy empty list should not be process at all as there is no data to create the filter expression. maybe I get it wrong, could you elaborate the use case?

Comment: @nighter Imagine you have some function taking list of (field, value) tuples as a parameter. This function returns the filter expression build in the way presented in the answer. And you want that this function is as general as possible: it works properly even if empty list is passed. Is such a case the result filter_expression should reject all DB objects. Also, imagine you have a list of conditions joined by __and__ operator. Then passing empty list you mean that filter expression shouldn't filter DB objects at all. I have a practical need for such features.

Comment: @Andriy if the list of conditions are empty and there are no other filter arguments, wouldn't just simply omit the `FilterExpression` (or whatever equivalent) argument for the `query` method be the solution then?  Also, as a matter of courtesy, please avoiding commenting on a 3+ year old thread with your own question, but instead ask a new question and refer to this thread if you feel your needs are novel.

Answer (score 1):

```
import operator
filter_exp = reduce(operator.or_, (Attr('teams').contains(x) for x in 'abc'))
```